# What is the practical use of getchar and putchar?

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

What are the practical uses of these functions? I mean if we use them using while loop and `EOF` we get just what we type like if we give input `"hello"` we will get the output as `"hello"`. So what's the point?

Comment: Maybe you want to store the input you get from getchar() and manipulate the data before you output it with putchar().

Answer (score 0):

Using `getchar` and `putchar` are simpler for character I/O because, they do not require a format string as do `scanf` and `printf`.

Also, `scanf` stores a data item in an object whose address is given by its argument, whereas `getchar` returns the value of the character read as its value. Both `scanf` and `getchar` return `EOF` as their value to indicate that the End-of-File has been reached, an invalid character has been read or to signal some other failure conditions.

So, `getchar` and `putchar` allows you to write solid code without dealing with the format of the input or the input.

Comment: end-of-file is a condition, not a marker. `getchar()` returns `EOF` to signal it failed. You can test the reason for failure with `ferror()` and/or `feof()`

Comment: @pmg EOF is used as the value returned by several functions to indicate that the End-of-File has been reached, an invalid character has been read or to signal some other failure conditions. EOF is a macro indicating several failures so, marker in a sense. But, I mentioned EOF generally in my answer. I don't see how you understood what you understood. Surely it's not a reason to downvote don't you think?

Comment: I guess it's a question of pedantism: the functions return `EOF` when they **fail to read data** (for one of several reasons), not when they read something.

Comment: @pmg I can see how my wording might misled some. I edited the answer to clarify the `EOF` part.

Answer (score -1):

`int getchar()` = Returns the next character from the standard input (stdin).

Basically read one character at a time.

`putchar(int)` = Writes a character to the standard output (stdout).

It allows you to deal with any type of input/output without knowing their exact data type. It provides more control and flexibility on IO operation. It is also faster than scanf/pritnf so you can use it in online programming competitions where lot of IO operations are required.